# Getting the sum from a UNION ALL result set

Tags: sql, oracle, union, rollup

I have a SQL query that takes several data points from each day across a window of time in a UNION ALL query, and then sums that data for each day in the result set.

What I want to add to the result set is a total at the bottom of ALL the days in the result set. I have tried to use ROLLUP (with the GROUP BY statement) with no success, and I keep getting the error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Not sure if there is a trick to ROLLUP with a UNION ALL, of if it will not work at all. I have also tried a temp table, and then perform a UNION ALL with the sum of the temp table, but this seems so complicated (and I have not been able to get it to work either).

Can someone please help guide me? Here is my working code:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(x) */
ACTIVITY_DAY
, SUM(ORDERED_UNITS)
, SUM(ORDERED_AMT)
FROM (
    SELECT ACTIVITY_DAY,ORDERED_UNITS,ORDERED_AMT FROM D_DAILY_ORDERS
        WHERE REGION_ID = 1
        AND MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
        AND ACTIVITY_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('20160409','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20160505','YYYYMMDD')
        AND ID IN ('B019433MGC', 'B019433O4C', 'B00STUX0F0', 'B017SL40S6', 'B00ZHJDJ5W', 'B00STUX276', 'B017SL44RI', 'B00ST415S0', 'B00ST414O0')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ACTIVITY_DAY,ORDERED_UNITS,ORDERED_AMT FROM D_DAILY_ORDERS
        WHERE REGION_ID = 1
        AND MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
        AND ACTIVITY_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('20160501','YYYYMMDD') AND TO_DATE('20160505','YYYYMMDD')
        AND ID IN ('B007V4YR5M', 'B00BHQ9CHI')
) x
GROUP BY ACTIVITY_DAY
ORDER BY ACTIVITY_DAY
;
```

Comment: I believe `rollup` is the right way; you simply have to use `GROUP BY ROLLUP(ACTIVITY_DAY)`. Can you please post the query giving error?

Comment: what is your rollup query version that raise that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, ROLLUP is the right way; you were probably having some syntax error:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    ACTIVITY_DAY
  3  , SUM(ORDERED_UNITS)
  4  , SUM(ORDERED_AMT)
  5  FROM (
  6      select sysdate   as ACTIVITY_DAY, 1 as ORDERED_UNITS, 10 as ORDERED_AMT from dual union all
  7      select sysdate-1 as ACTIVITY_DAY, 2 as ORDERED_UNITS, 20 as ORDERED_AMT from dual union all
  8      select sysdate-1 as ACTIVITY_DAY, 2 as ORDERED_UNITS, 20 as ORDERED_AMT from dual
  9  ) x
 10  GROUP BY rollup(ACTIVITY_DAY)
 11  ORDER BY ACTIVITY_DAY
 12  ;

ACTIVITY_ SUM(ORDERED_UNITS) SUM(ORDERED_AMT)
--------- ------------------ ----------------
15-MAG-16                  4               40
16-MAG-16                  1               10
                           5               50
```